# How can I change the text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<div class="basePrice">$99.99</div>
```

I want to change the value $99.99 using JavaScript.

I tried using `getElementByClass` but it didn't produce the results that I was hoping to get.

Comment: Are you using a framework such as jQuery, or just pure JavaScript?  Also, can you post the code you tried that didn't work?

Comment: Well `getElementByClass` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClass` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which is kind of like an array.

You have to specify which element (there's only one here, so I'm assuming the first) you're looking for, and then you can use [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to change the text of the node.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("basePrice")[0].textContent = "$49.99";
```

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("basePrice")[0].textContent = "$49.99";
```

```html
<div class="basePrice">$99.99</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that like so

```
document.querySelector('.basePrice').innerHTML = 'different text'
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/m7zrsnfs/)

Answer (score 0):

try getElementByClassName I believe is the proper syntax.